# problem with MaskedEditValidator in ASP.NET AJAX

Tags: asp.net-ajax, maskededitextender

I have text box to enter a phone number. I'm using AJAX MaskedEditExtender and MaskedEditValidator to validate the phone.

I have no problem with mask but the problem nothing happen when I enter for example only 3 number then lose the focus but as soon the focus on I will see the error message and it will disappear as soon as I write one number.

all what I want to get the error message if the user did not enter 9 numbers after lose the focus.

here is my code:

Comment: I did but still can not see my code here!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed to assign some of the MaskedEditValidator property which is extender to validate.